# Error when trying to move to next element of a Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am dealing with linked lists, and am having issues moving to the next element of the Linked List. the error that I get is:
`error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'item' from type 'struct item *`

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct item
{
    float size;
    struct item *next;
} item;

item head, curr, tail;
```

...

```
head.next = (item*) malloc(sizeof(item));
curr = head.next;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this assignment statement

```
curr = head.next;
```

`curr` has type `item` while `head.next` has type `item *`. That is the first one is a structure object and the second one is a pointer. They are incompatible.

Thus the compiler issues an error.

You should declare variable `curr` like pointer

```
item *curr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based in your description, you want to make `curr` the next node of the linked list (?).

In that case, you should assign the memory direction of `curr` to `head.next`. How, you may ask ?:

```
item head, curr;   // declaration of variables

head.size = 8;
curr.size = 5;

head.next = &curr; // making 'curr' the next node
```

Now, in the memory you will have something like this (memory addresses are just arbitraries numbers):

[Memory example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx7fg.png)

**NOTE**: Pointers keep memory addresses. That's why you assign them the return value of `malloc()`, which give the memory direction of an available "memory chunk" with the expecified length.